# Accessing columns on an dataframes in python

Tags: pandas

I;m doing a ML project as part of my Mtech through a work integrated Learning program on which I need to read through bug database(output in csv) and then do some analysis.
as part of this, I;m using a pandas dataframe to load the CSV datafile but unable to access each of the column by name or Index. The example available in google does mention about accessing it by name or Index but neither of it is working for me. just curious to know if I;m missing anything here.

```
df.columns

Index(['Identifier,Status,Priority,Severity,Found,DE-manager,Age,Component,Headline'], dtype='object')
```

but when i access by Index or name it gives the following error

df[0] or df['Identifier'] yields the same result.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/nlp_course/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ramFn.png)

Comment: can you show what is the result of df.head(5) ? It seems to me that it is a problem of parsing when reading the data. df.columns shows like you only have one big column `'Identifier,Status,Priority,Severity,Found,DE-manager,Age,Component,Headline'`. So maybe you used the wrong separator when reading

Comment: It may help if you show us a sample of your original data, and also how you loaded it using pandas

Comment: I have added the data requested as an image file .

Comment: It is better to put your data as code rather than images. it allows us to copy paste and test  quickly. Nevertheless it seems to be a problem of separator. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as a problem of separator. You may solve it specifying comma as your separator :

```py
df = pd.read_csv("bug_report.csv", sep=",")
```

You don't need to convert the result of `pd.read_csv` to dataframe as it is already a dataframe